# Multiplatform messaging app with offline message support

Tags: offline, chat, cross-platform

I'm looking for a messaging app with the following requisites:

- multiplatform (Android, Linux, Windows)
- supports offline messages (If I send a message to someone that is offline, the receiver should get the message when s/he gets back online, not when we happen to be both online again)
- doesn't use phone number as user ID
- synchronizes chats across devices